# Should I use Py_INCREF for any of my PyObjects in this block? Also am I Py_DECREFing my objects correctly?

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, reference-counting

Whenever I call this function, memory usage is increases a lot per call, so I think there is some memory leak here.

```
PyObject *pScript, *pModule, *pFunc, *pValue;
PyObject *pArgs = NULL;
long ret = 1;

// Initialize python, set system path and load the module
pScript = SetPyObjectString(PYTHON_SCRIPT_NAME);
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('"PYTHON_SCRIPT_PATH"')");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pScript);
Py_XDECREF(pScript);

if (pModule != NULL) {
    // Get function object from python module
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, operation.c_str());

    if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
        // Create argument(s) as Python tuples
        if (operation == UPDATE_KEY) {
            // If operation is Update key, create two arguments - key and value
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
        }
        else {
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
        }

        pValue = SetPyObjectString(key.c_str());
        // Set argument(s) with key/value strings
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
        if (operation == UPDATE_KEY) {
            // If operation is Update key, set two arguments - key and value
            pValue = SetPyObjectString(value.c_str());
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue);
        }

        // Call the function using function object and arguments
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        Py_XDECREF(pArgs);

        if (pValue != NULL) {
            // Parse the return values
            ret = PyLong_AsLong(PyList_GetItem(pValue, 0));
            value = GetPyObjectString(PyList_GetItem(pValue, 1));
        }
        else {
            ERROR("Function call to %s failed", operation.c_str());
        }

        Py_XDECREF(pValue);
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
    }
    else {
        ERROR("Cannot find function in python module");
    }
    Py_XDECREF(pModule);
}
else {
    ERROR("Failed to load python module");
}
```

I am leaking some memory when this C++ snippet in my code calls the python script and I want to know why. I think I am doing something wrong with my Py_DECREFs. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're missing at least one decref—what if `pFunc` is not null, but it's not callable? And you reassign a new value to `pValue` without releasing the old one. You might be missing more, but you really should use a memory debugger rather than trying to guess by inspection. Or, even better—if you're using C++, not C, why not use PyCXX or boost::python or some other C++ wrapper that uses RAII to take care of the refcounting for you?

Comment: @abarnert I cannot use any other wrapper because this is a small part of a big project that has a lot of dependencies. It is difficult to use anything other than the default Python C API. Can you take look at the PyObjects pArgs and pValue? I don't understand which function needs a DECREF and which one needs a INCREF

Comment: You can use PyCXX locally in a big project, You may not be able to use some of the higher-level features like the extension-builder facility or the Python<->STL conversions, but you can easily use just the smart pointers. Or, if not, you can write your own smart pointer. But really, if you can't understand what needs a DECREF you really shouldn't be writing this code. Getting the refcounting right is no something you can do through copying and pasting code you don't understand and shotgun-debugging it until it seems to work.

Comment: Okay I will look into PyCXX or boost::python. Thanks!

Comment: @VenkatKrishnan If you are looking for wrappers, I recommend [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.org/).

Comment: @VenkatKrishnan you should not program the Python C API without the documentation in front of you. For any call you make, unless the documentation says it returns a "borrowed reference" then you MUST decref it. If the reference is borrowed, then you must NOT decref it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted one missing decref from a quick glance:

---

```
pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, operation.c_str());

if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
    // ...
    Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
}
```

This will leak any non-callable attribute matching `operation`.

---

The two reassignments of `pValue`… I think that's OK, because [`PyTuple_SetItem`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_SetItem) steals the reference to each of the original values.

---

For this line that you asked about:

```
value = GetPyObjectString(PyList_GetItem(pValue, 1));
```

The [`PyList_GetItem`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_GetItem) returns a borrowed reference, so the fact that you don't decref it is correct.

But I don't see the declaration for `value` anywhere, or `GetPyObjectString`, so I have no idea what that part is doing. Maybe it's just getting a borrowed buffer out of a `PyUnicodeObject *` and copying it into some C++ `wstring` or UTF-32 string type, or maybe it's leaking a Python object or a copied buffer, or returning a raw C buffer that you just leak here, or… who knows?

---

But I certainly wouldn't trust that some guy on the internet found all of them on a quick scan. Learn to use a memory debugger.

Or: You're using C++. RAII is almost the whole point of using C++—in other words, instead of using raw `PyObject *` values, you can use a smart pointer that decrefs things for you automatically. Or, even better, use a ready-made library like [PyCXX](http://cxx.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Okay thanks. This is what I was looking for. I was confused because of this https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#ownership-rules. It says PyTuple_SetItem() takes over ownership. I will use two different PyObjects for this now. Also, `ret = PyLong_AsLong(PyList_GetItem(pValue, 0));` in this line, should I DECREF anything?

Comment: @VenkatKrishnan Oops, I may have missed that. I’ll check and update the answer if I got it wrong. I haven’t written raw C API extensions for anything nontrivial in a long time—if I can’t use Cython, or PyCXX, or RustPy, etc., I usually just create a plain C API and write the bindings in Python with cffi or ctypes. In part because this stuff is a pain to debug. But you’re not even trying to debug it, just trying to get it right statically, which makes it even more painful.